# Is the rank of Imams (spiritually) higher than other prophets? (Except Prophet Mohammad (s)) (Shia view)

Tags: shiism, prophets, shia-imam

I know that the rank of "Prophet Mohammad" (s) is higher than Imams and other people, but somebody orally told me that:

> the rank of the Imams (I mean 12 Imams of Shiite [Shia]) is spiritually higher than the rank of all the prophets other than Prophet Mohammad(s).

So, is there any tradition regarding mentioned issue?

*(Note: I am looking for the perspective of Shiite according to the Ahadith)*

Comment: "Other prophets"? I thought Imams weren't prophets.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, of course.** Actually, the rank of (Shia Islam) Imams is higher than all prophets (except Prophet Mohammad [peace be upon him and his family]).

More explanation:

> It has been stated in our religious teachings that all prophets and
>   messengers have no advantage and virtue over the imams, other than the
>   fact that they bear prophethood, while the imams are the bearers of
>   whatever knowledge all of the prophets before them ever possessed.
>   Also, according to hadiths, “The Great Name” of Allah (swt) consists
>   of seventy three “letters” in which the prophets only knew a few of;
>   even Prophet Ibrahim (pbuh) only knew eight of those “letters”, while
>   Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) was aware of all but one of them and passed on
>   this knowledge to the imams (as) after him.

To read the complete illustration, you can refer to the source of the answer, as following:

- [www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa6067)